# Restart celery worker consumer connection to broker

Tags: python, celery

I've found an example of how to restart worker connection in celery docs (http://docs.openquake.org/celery-2.4.6/userguide/workers.html#writing-your-own-remote-control-commands):

```py
from celery.worker.control import Panel

@Panel.register
def reset_connection(panel):
    panel.logger.critical("Connection reset by remote control.")
    panel.consumer.reset_connection()
    return {"ok": "connection reset"}
```

But it's only available in Celery 3.0 and earlier. There is no such function in Consumer class on Celery 3.1.

How do I re-establish connection to broker now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The worker internals was rewritten to use "bootsteps" in 3.1 (see http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/extending.html)

I think best way to reset the broker connection from a remote control command would be to use `panel.consumer.connection.close()` instead:

```
from celery.worker.control import Panel, logger as control_logger

@Panel.register
def reset_connection(state):
    control_logger.critical("Connection reset by remote control.")
    state.consumer.connection.close()
    return {"ok": "connection reset"}
```

This will force the worker to restart all Consumer related bootsteps (see the graph in the link above)

Incidentally, the `panel` argument was renamed `state` but you can name it however you like.  The logger is no longer available on the state, so you have to import it.

Comment: Thanks for help, Ask! I'll take a closer look at bootsteps.